# question regarding execution sequence of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

hello friends my question is i am having two function f1 and f2 and if i want to execute function f2 after execution of f1 how is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to execute `f2` automatically whenever you invoke `f1`?? If so *function wrapping* will be the answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
f1();
f2();
```

JavaScript is single-threaded, so code is executed linear-ly (is that a word?).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be a little bit more clear about that

You can have

```
function f2(){
}

function f1(){
   //do something
   f2();
}
```

or

```
function f2(){
}

function f1(){
}

function f3(){
   f1();
   f2();
}
```